# rxtools not installed

Tags: ros, rxtools

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone, I'm taking the first steps in ROS studing, and i have a question. I installed ROS kinetic and it works fine, but when I call any comand  from rxtools package, I get a message that the comand not found, what could be the problem?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270550/rxtools-not-installed/) by [Amrello](https://answers.ros.org/users/31839/amrello/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-09-09

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-09-09**:
I have the impression that you're trying to follow some tutorial or howto, and that that is telling you to start something from `rxtools`. It would be good to know whether that is true, and which tutorial or howto it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[rxtools](http://wiki.ros.org/rxtools) is a *very* old package and has been replaced by [rqt](http://wiki.ros.org/rqt) quite some time ago.

> when I call any comand from rxtools package, I get a message that the comand not found, what could be the problem?

Well, technically of course the problem is that the package is really not installed. There is no release of `rxtools` for Kinetic.

I would suggest you try and achieve whatever you're trying to do with `rqt` and one of its plugins.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0